# operator[] of vector container - return reference?

Tags: c++, vector

I made a class named  **CardDeck** (c++) which has `vector<card*> deck` private member.

I overloaded operator[] to this class like this :

```
Card* CardDeck::operator[](int i) const{
return this->deck[i];}
```

where you can see it returns **Card*** and not **Card* &**. When I tried putting Card*& it didnt compile, though ,from what I understand vector[i] return the ith element **reference**- like is written [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/).

So how come it would compile like this and not with Card* & ?

Comment: What error message did the compiler give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return a non-`const` reference from a `const` member function since it would allow the caller to modify the object. Just return a copy of the `Card*`, as your example does, or if you want to allow the caller to modify the pointer, don't mark your function as `const`.

Also note, you can have both, if you want to be able to access the values from a `const` context and modify them from a non-`const` context:

```
Card* CardDeck::operator[]( int i ) const;
Card*& CardDeck::operator[]( int i );
```

Comment: ... and note that modifying the pointer in the vector is distinct from modifying the card through the pointer!

Comment: I'd make that a `Card const*` in the const version. Don't want have your internals modifiable in a const function.